# How to call repository from service Android Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, repository-pattern, dagger-hilt

I use Dagger Hilt in my app and want to call repository method getRandomWordForNotification() from AlarmService. How can I do it so as to implement the commented code sticking to MVVM pattern?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmService(name: String = "AlarmService"): IntentService(name) {
    //private var word: Def? = null

    override fun onHandleIntent(p0: Intent?) {
        val i = Intent(applicationContext, ListFragment::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, i, 0)

        //word = repository.getRandomRandomWordForNotification().value

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this.applicationContext, "channelID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Daily Reminder")
            .setContentText(/*"${word!!.text} - ${word!!.tr[0].text}"*/"")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
        notificationManager.notify(123, notification)
    }
}
```

```
class DictionaryRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val dictionaryDao: DictionaryDao,
    private val dictionaryApi: DictionaryApi
) {
    suspend fun getTranslation(text: String) = dictionaryApi.getTranslation(text=text)

    suspend fun upsert(def: Def) = dictionaryDao.upsert(def)

    fun getAllTranslations() = dictionaryDao.getAllTranslations()

    fun getTranslationsSize() = dictionaryDao.getTranslationsSize()

    fun getRandomTranslations() = dictionaryDao.getRandomTranslations()

    fun getRandomRandomWordForNotification() = dictionaryDao.getRandomWordForNotification()

    suspend fun deleteTranslation(def: Def) = dictionaryDao.deleteTranslation(def)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay - >

fisrt of all make an interface for example:

```
interface RepositoryHandler {
    fun getRandomNotification(notificationNumber: Int)
}
```

then use it as parameter of AlarmServie fox example:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmService(val repositoryHandler: RepositoryHandler,name: String = "AlarmService"): IntentService(name) {
    //private var word: Def? = null

    override fun onHandleIntent(p0: Intent?) {

//////////////////// use repositoryHandler.getRandomNotification(number of notifications)

    }
}
```

> Then

```
    class DictionaryRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val dictionaryDao: DictionaryDao,
    private val dictionaryApi: DictionaryApi
):NotificatonHandler{
 -------------------------
}
```

> Then u should Provide DictionaryRepository in app module

```
 @Binds
 @Singletone
fun bindDictionaryRepository(dictionaryRepository:DictionaryRepository): RepositoryHandler
```

> Then in your ViewModel inject RepositoryHandler

**please vote answer if that helps**